# Converting java JSONObject to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a JSONObject I'm sending through AJAX.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("nbLike", result);
obj.put("username", "bill");
```

Then in the success function I want to access the **obj** `properties`. eg : username

I'have tried with `JSON.parse(obj)` but I got an error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`

*server side the log shows* : `{"username":"bill","nbLike":1} //log.info(obj)`

*client side the log show*  : `['username':'bill', 'nbLike':1] //console.log(result)`

I'd like something like :

```
console.log("Username : " + obj.username)
```

Thank you

Comment: have you tries `obj['username']` ?

Comment: Yes. I got `unedfined`

Comment: please provide relevant code of your ajax request.

Comment: Im using AjaxForm library : `form.ajaxForm(function(result) {console.log(result)}`

Comment: Check for the extra single quote `'` anywhere in your script

Comment: DDK as you can see in the log output there is no extra single cote

Comment: Can you throw this into a jsfiddle? should be relatively easy to fix if we can see it.

Comment: I will keep looking to find the error myself and if I cant find it I will provide a Fiddle

Comment: From java, before sending, convert it into string `obj.toString()`, on javascript end, use it as `console.log("Username : " + JSON.parse(obj.username))`. String is something both javascript and java understand by default.

Comment: @MIdhunKrishna: `console.log("Username : " + JSON.parse(obj).username)` if at all…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert JSONObject to String before sending it to frontend and add "application/json" to Content-type of your response. Then you can use it as simple js object, don't need to convert it.